# How to make conditional query filters in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

According to the [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) documentation we can't use multiple query filters for an entity, we can only have one, with multiple conditions in it:

> *It is currently not possible to define multiple query filters on the same entity - only the last one will be applied. However, you can define a single filter with multiple conditions using the logical AND operator (&& in C#).*

So, in a project I'm working on with EF Core 3.1, I tried to do just that. In my query filter I try to apply a condition for a `TenantId` and a condition for `IsDeleted`:

```
internal Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> QueryFilters<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class {
    return _ => (TenantId.HasValue
                 && _ is ITenantableEntity
                 && ((ITenantableEntity)_).TenantId == new TenantId(TenantId.Value)
                    || true)
                && (_ is IDeletableEntity
                    && !((IDeletableEntity)_).IsDeleted
                    || true);
}
```

The `TenantId` is defined as a property on the `DbContext`:

```
internal int? TenantId => _identity.TenantId;
```

The problem I'm running into is that in certain scenarios, such as Hangfire background jobs, the `TenantId` will always be null. I thought I was guarding for that in the above condition, but when I tried it out, the following query parameters were generated:

```
queryContext.AddParameter(
    name: "__ef_filter__HasValue_0",
    value: (object)Invoke(queryContext => Convert(Convert(queryContext.Context, DbContext).TenantId.HasValue, Object), queryContext)
);
queryContext.AddParameter(
    name: "__ef_filter__p_1",
    value: (object)Invoke(queryContext => Convert(Convert(new TenantId(Convert(queryContext.Context, DbContext).TenantId.Value), Nullable`1), Object), queryContext)
);
```

And because of those parameters, the queries are simply crashing with a NRE. Is there a better or more appropirate way to build up the expression in the query filter so that if the `TenantId` does have a value, the parameter is generated, and not otherwise without the nested conditional I've got going?

To make the query in the background job succeed, I have to use `IgnoreQueryFilters()`, which fixes the `TenantId` check, but now also ignores the `IsDeleted` check which I'd like to continue to have.

Comment: Have you found out the solution? I'm getting same issue, whenever it checks HasValue, it's stuck at the initialized value, value set from the first call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is how you handle the global filter query but how you execute your background jobs.

The TenantId and any other information dependent of the logged user will not be available to hangfire jobs.

You could easily solve it by [passing the appropriate parameters](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-arguments.html) to your background jobs, this way hangfire will serialize it in the DB and deserialize it when it runs.

```
private long currentTenantId = loggedUser.GetTenantId(); // or any other way to get the tenantId when the background job was scheduled.
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ISomeService>(s => s.SomeFunction(currentTenantId));
```

If you look at the hangfire `Job` table you will notice that the `InvocationData` and `Arguments` columns will hold all the information needed to  run `SomeFunction()`.